# div or section for forms with a heading in html5?

Tags: html

I just want to know the correct way of putting a form on a page with html5. I can't seem to find anything regarding forms.

My page is a contact page with the content in an article element with heading and all (Wordpress pages). I'm adding a contact form to the page and it has a heading. Should they be in a `<section>` or a `<div>`?

```
<div>
  <h3>title</h3>
  <form></form>
</div>
```

or

```
<section>
  <header>
    <h3>title</h3
  </header>
  <form></form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTML5 Spec defines it as -

> The section element represents a section of a document, typically with a title or heading.

So, I would suggest the **form with a heading** to be placed in a section with the format you have specified.